# Sorting Primary Entities on Properties of Doubly-Nested Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, ef-core-6.0

I'm using Entity Framework Core with ASP.Net MVC.  My business object model consists, in part, of Jobs (the primary entities), each of which contains one or more Projects, and each Project has zero or more Schedules (which link to sets of Departments, but that's not important here).  Each schedule has a StartDate and and EndDate.

Here is a (simplified) class diagram (which reflects the database schema as you would expect):

[image: Class Diagram]

I want to sort the Jobs list by the earliest StartDateTime value in the Schedule entity. I haven't been able to come up with a LINQ chain that accomplishes this.  For the time being, I have cobbed the functionality I want by using ADO.Net directly in my controller to assemble the Jobs list based on the following SQL Statement:

```
@"SELECT
    Jobs.JobId, 
    Jobs.JobName, 
    Jobs.jobNumber,
    MIN(ProjectSchedules.StartDateTime) AS StartDateTime
FROM 
    Jobs INNER JOIN Projects ON Jobs.JobID = Projects.JobID
         LEFT JOIN ProjectSchedules ON Projects.ProjectID = ProjectSchedules.ProjectID
GROUP BY Jobs.JobId, Jobs.JobName, Jobs.JobNumber 
ORDER BY StartDateTime"
```

I would prefer to use EF Core properly, rather than to do an end-run around it.  What would be the LINQ statements to generate this SQL statement (or an equivalent one)?

Comment: Would you mind showing the class model with navigation properties, and using a tag for the EF version (like [ef-core-6.0])?

Comment: I've set up navigation in both directions up and down the tree of classes shown in the diagram.  EF-Core version is 6, as opposed to 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a query that "collects" all `StartDateTime`s in schedules of projects per job, takes their lowest value then sorts by that value:

```cs
context.Jobs
    .OrderBy(j => j.Projects
        .SelectMany(p => p.Schedules)
        .Select(s => s.StartDate).OrderBy(d => d).First())
    .Select(j => new { ... })
```

As you see, there's not even a `Min` function in there. The function could be used, but it may perform worse, because it has to evaluate all `StartDate` values, while the ordering *could* make use of an ordered index.

Either way, for comparison, this is with `Min()`:

```cs
context.Jobs
    .OrderBy(j => j.Projects
        .SelectMany(p => p.Schedules)
        .Select(s => s.StartDate).Min())
```

Comment: Thank you!  I've just started learning LINQ.  I can see that it works a somewhat differently from SQL.  I normally think in terms of first building a table of data, and only then specifying how it should be ordered.  But LINQ reverses the order in some cases.  Interesting...

Answer (score 0):

First we need to retrieve all the entities we can do this with the Include statement, and we use theninclude to retrieve entities one further down.

`dbcontext.Jobs.Include(j => j.Projects).ThenInclude(p => p.Schedules)`

Now that we have all the entities you can do all the sorting, grouping or whatever else you wish to do.

To me it sounds like you want to `Orderby` on `schedule.startdatetime`.

Comment: So, if I understand what you're saying, I should do separate LINQ method calls.  The first one pulls all the Job, Project, and Schedule data into memory, and then the next sorts the list in the application server's memory, rather than sorting on the SQL Server.  Correct me if I'm wrong about my understanding.I don't normally worry about performance optimization too early, but as the database grows, I could pulling and sorting a lot of data, since I can't know a Job's start date until I have the tree of its Projects and Schedules.

Comment: I'm sorry your use case is not entirely clear to me. Do you ONLY want to retrieve the entity with the earliest startdate? Or do you want to retrieve them ALL and show them sorted on their startdate. Because if you want to only retrieve the earliest startdate you should use a ```.First()``` or ```FirstOrDefault()``` depending on context ofcourse and then you can just do the ordering in the database.

(performance wise i'm not sure what would be best)

Comment: Depending on your setup you could also simply query the earliest start date and then reverse the relationships. So select from ```Schedule``` and ```include``` upwards

Comment: Hmm...that's an interesting idea.  I'll have to play around with that and see what happens.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and I do want the whole list.  I'll be paging them on a landing page, sorted by date, either ascending or descending, according to user's choice.  The only reason for the MIN() statement in my SQL is because I need to get the earliest start date from all the schedules in all the Projects in each job.  (I just noticed that I'm not explicitly ordering the Jobs in the top-level of the SQL, but it's working anyway...